# rsync error: syntax or usage error

Tags: ssh, rsync, putty

I am trying to copy local system folder files to remote server. tried below command in ssh using putty :

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh' C:\wamp64\www\magento3 user@111.11.11.111:/var/www/html
```

but it gave error  :

[image]

Comment: Your source path `C:\wamp64\www\magento3` looks like a Windows path. Is that correct? In that case rsync is interpreting both source and destination as remote, I think because there is a `:` in the source path.

Comment: @Thomas yes, its windows 7 , now what is the alternative solution for this ?

Comment: mount the windows folder

Comment: I use rsync with `machine:path`  where your C could be interpreted as a remote NFS (networked file system) machine named C

Comment: @spylh9999ggr: so you are using putty on Win7 to connect to a remote Linux machine and want to `rsync` on the remote Linux machine files of the Windows machine to a second Linux machine? What is your actual problem, because this one is a typical XY problem.

Comment: @Thomas  I want to copy files from windows local system to server [ built on ubuntu ]

Comment: Then use WinSCP or MobaXterm or FileZilla, which are Windows tools to copy files between Windows and Linux world using scp/ssh. Or you could set up a fileserver as suggested by others.

Comment: @Thomas we have very large amount of files to transfer, its not possible wit filezilla.... i am researching on `mouning the windows folder` as suggested by others.....

Comment: @daisy can you give me commands to `mount the windows folder`

Comment: @guiverc can you tell me what commands i need to use ?

Comment: This is a windows related problem.

Comment: @Rinzwind i need to transfer files from windows to ubuntu server......

Comment: @Thomas thanks for support, i found solution that making the zip file of all the files and than copy to filezilla and than run command : `unzip [filename].zip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to change your working directory to C:\wamp64\www. Your rsync command then would look like:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh' magento3 user@111.11.11.111:/var/www/html
```

rsync won't see C: then and accordingly won't consider it a remote system.

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me how to change working directory to `C:\wamp64\www` what commands i need to run for this ? is i need to run in local windows system or in ubuntu server ?

Comment: i ran commands as suggested by you as  here : http://prntscr.com/gjq7hr , but it gave me error as in screenshot , so i tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493309/cwrsync-in-windows-not-being-recognised, still i am seeing same issue....

Comment: now i am seeing this message  : https://prnt.sc/gjqtfz

Comment: thanks for support, i found solution that making the zip file of all the files and than copy to filezilla and than run command : `unzip [filename].zip`